# Angular directive doesnt work on view change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have resize on my main container, but it works when I first land on that page, but when I go to another page then back the directive fails to load.

This seem to be happening with other functions too, I tried jquery way and it still has the same effect.

```
 appControllers.directive('resize', function ($window) {


    return function (scope, element) {

        var w = angular.element($window);
        var bb = angular.element(document.querySelector( '#bh' ));

        scope.$watch( function() {
            return bb.outerHeight();

        }, function (newValue, oldValue) {  
             scope.topHeight = $(window).outerHeight() - bb.outerHeight() + 90;
            return scope.$apply();

        });

        bb.bind('resize', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: This doesn't feel like good way to achieve what you are trying to achieve. Plus directive is not supposed to be programmed for specific element but it should be attachable to any element. Can you create plnkr for it? BTW I guess refreshing the page after pressing back button works and you are using angular routing.

Comment: Yes I am, can you tell me the quick solution?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. any luck on this?